# Finding the projection onto the space of constant functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let's consider the space $L^3(0,1)$ and it's subspace $\mathcal{C}$ of constant functions. Since $L^3$ is uniformly convex, the metric projection onto a closed, convex subset is well defined. Therefore the projection onto $\mathcal{C}$ is well defined. Now the question is: it's easy in $L^2$ to prove that the projection of a function onto $\mathcal{C}$ is precisely it's  mean value. What about the projection in $L^3$? Does somebody have some ideas on how to calculate this projection?

Thanks a lot in advance for any advice.

Comment: IIRC the existence of a projection map (i.e., in this case, for each $f \in L^3(0, 1)$ existence and uniqueness of $c \in \mathcal C$ minimizing $||f - c||$, rather than just existence) requires not just convexity but uniform convexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The projection is well-defined since the $L^3$-norm is strictly convex. The necessary (and sufficient) condition for $z\in \mathbb R$ to minimize $\frac13\|u-c\|_{L^3}^3$ is
$$
\int_0^1 (u-z)^2 sign(u-z) =0.
$$
Denote $I:=\{x: \ u(x) \ge z\}$. Then this is equivalent to
$$
\int_{I} (u-z)^2 = \int_{I^c} (u-z)^2.
$$
So to find $z$, one has to balance both sides of the equations. I doubt there is a closed form expression that is valid for all $u$.

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for: $z$ such that balances both sides of that equation. I'm aware that probably there is not a closed form for $z$, but never say never.